# Opinión de este código JS usando POO

Tags: javascript, poo

Estoy practicando la programación orientada a objetos con Javascript. En la mayor parte de ejemplos de POO de cualquier lenguaje ponen el ejemplo del objeto **coche** por eso para practicar me he basado en esto.

La cuestión es, el código funciona y hace todo lo que tiene que hacer pero cómo podría mejorarlo? O qué cosas debería de tener en cuenta cuando programe con orientación a objetos? Seguramente hay cosas que habré hecho mal o errores de novato.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rytkp6cw/) con el código

Código JS:

```js
class coche {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el

    //engine status
    this.status = false
    //hardcoded
    this.el.style.left = 0
    this.el.style.position = 'absolute'

    //variable
    this.left = 0
    this.width = 0
    this.height = 0
    this.direction = 0
    this.color = 'transparent'       
  }

  setWidth(width) { 
    this.el.width = this.width = width
    this.el.style.width = this.el.width + 'px'}

  setHeight(height) { 
    this.el.height = this.height = height
    this.el.style.height = this.el.height + 'px' }

  setColor(color) { this.el.style.background = this.el.color = this.color = color }

  setDirection(direction) {
    this.el.direction = this.direction += direction
    this.el.style.transform = `rotate(${this.direction}deg)`

    this.direction < 0 ? (this.direction + 360) : null
    this.direction >= 360 ? (this.direction - 360) : null
  }

  goForward(distance) { 
    this.left += distance
    this.el.left = this.distance
    this.el.style.left = this.left + 'px'
  }
  goBack(distance) { 
    this.left += distance
    this.el.left = this.distance
    this.el.style.left = this.left + 'px'
  }
  startEngine() {
    this.el.status = this.status = true
    document.getElementById('r-r').style.background = 'red'
    document.getElementById('r-l').style.background = 'red'
    document.getElementById('f-r').style.background = 'yellow'
    document.getElementById('f-l').style.background = 'yellow'
    document.getElementById('start').style.background = 'lime'
    document.getElementById('stop').style.background = 'red'
  }
  stopEngine() {
    this.el.status = this.status = false
    document.getElementById('r-r').style.background = 'white'
    document.getElementById('r-l').style.background = 'white'
    document.getElementById('f-r').style.background = 'white'
    document.getElementById('f-l').style.background = 'white'
    document.getElementById('start').style.background = 'red'
    document.getElementById('stop').style.background = 'lime'
  }
}

// DOM BUTTONS
const forward = document.getElementById('forward')
const back = document.getElementById('back')
const right = document.getElementById('right')
const left = document.getElementById('left')
const setWidth = document.getElementById('setWidth');
const setHeight = document.getElementById('setHeight');
const setColor = document.getElementById('setColor');
const startEngine = document.getElementById('start');
const stopEngine = document.getElementById('stop');
const c1 = document.getElementById('coche')

const coche1 = new coche(c1)
coche1.setWidth(200)
coche1.setHeight(100)
coche1.setColor('gainsboro')

forward.onclick = function() {
    coche1.status ? coche1.goForward(20) :  alert('The engine is off')
} 
back.onclick = function() {
    coche1.status ? coche1.goBack(-20) :  alert('The engine is off')

}
right.onclick = function() {
    coche1.status ? coche1.setDirection(10) :  alert('The engine is off')

}
left.onclick = function() {
    coche1.status ? coche1.setDirection(-10) :  alert('The engine is off')

}
setWidth.onclick = function() {
    const width = document.getElementById('width').value
    coche1.setWidth(width)
}
setHeight.onclick = function() {
    const height = document.getElementById('height').value
    coche1.setHeight(height)
}
setColor.onclick = function() {
    const color = document.getElementById('color').value
    coche1.setColor(color)
}
startEngine.onclick = function() {
    !coche1.status ? coche1.startEngine() :  alert('The engine is already on')
}
stopEngine.onclick = function() {
    coche1.status ? coche1.stopEngine() :  alert('The engine is already on')
}
```

```css
#commandsTable {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
#commandsTable > tr {
  width: 100%;
}
#r-r, #r-l {
    width: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    background: white;
    border:     1px solid black;
}
#r-r {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#r-l {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#f-r, #f-l {
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    border:     1px solid black;

}
#f-r {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#f-l {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="commands">
  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>ENGINE</th>
          <td>
              <button id="stop" style="background: lime">Stop</button>
          </td>
          <td>
              <button id="start" style="background: red">Start</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>
              Specs
          </th>
          <td colspan="2">
              <input type="text" id="width" value="200">
          </td>
          <td >
              <input type="text" id="height" value="100">
          </td>
          <td >
             <input type="text" id="color" value="gainsboro">
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>
              Submit Specs
          </th>
          <td colspan="2">
              <button id="setWidth">Set Width</button>
          </td>
          <td >
              <button id="setHeight">Set Height</button>
          </td>
          <td >
              <button id="setColor">Set Color</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <style>
     
  </style>
  <table id="commandsTable">
      <tr>
          <td>
              <button id="forward">Go Forward</button>
          </td>

          <td>
              <button id="back">Go Back</button>
          </td>
          <td>
              <button id="right">Right</button>
          </td>
          <td>
              <button id="left">Left</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="coche">
 
  <div id="f-r"></div>
  <div id="f-l"></div>
 
  <div id="r-r"></div>
  <div id="r-l"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: no te vendría mal mirarte también el modelo vista controlador, eliminar los estilos html inline y separar las clases de los objetos. De todas formas la programación orientada a objetos es muy robusta y no es lo más eficiente, aunque sirve para mantener una buena estructura y organización del código, claro que si luego tienes todo el código en 2 ficheros no avanzas nada.

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar css fuera del html, minificado y compilado de sass. Las clases en un directorio aparte e importadas en tu fichero principal, solo llamando a las que necesites y el html que tire de variables con el contenido que necesites mandado por tu fichero principal que sería el controlador, el cual hace las llamadas necesarias a otro fichero (modelo) que establece las conexiones y recoge datos de la base de datos.

Comment: para mi las acciones forward , back, right son propias de la clase carro , o una clase padre llamada vehiculos , y coche extienda de vehiculos, y en vez de programar las acciones en un js, le colocaria las clases los listener, pero de igual forma creo que debes mejorar la pregunta por que se basaa en opiniones

Comment: Así en general... empezaría por que el botón de `start` y `stop` sean el mismo... :b